# Configuration file contains errors

Tags: postgresql

I have the following pg_hba.conf file:

```
    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
    host    all             all             172.18.0.4/32           trust
```

But when I run `postgres`, I get the following error:

```
prikshetsharma@Prikshets-MacBook-Pro deployment % docker run --name postgres --network datomic-network -t humboi/postgres
2021-08-08 07:49:58.363 GMT [7] LOG:  syntax error in file "/postgres_init/pg_hba.conf" line 2, near token "all"
2021-08-08 07:49:58.363 GMT [7] LOG:  syntax error in file "/postgres_init/pg_hba.conf" line 3, near token "all"
2021-08-08 07:49:58.363 GMT [7] FATAL:  configuration file "/postgres_init/pg_hba.conf" contains errors
```

How to fix this?

Here's the docker container that's running this postgres:

```
  0 FROM postgres:latest
  1 ARG VERSION
  2
  3 COPY postgres_init /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  4 USER postgres
  5 RUN initdb
  6 CMD postgres -c config_file=/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/pg_hba.conf
```

Comment: Any invisible but illegal characters maybe? Check the file with a hex editor or rewrite it by hand.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling it that pg_hba is the main config file (which is normally spelled postgresql.conf).  It is not the right format for that file.

Comment: i am stuck on a similar error but i am slightly confused by your answer. do you mean that the connections settings cant be defined in the file (pg_hba.conf) as such or does it have to be defined in another manner? Best.

Comment: He was telling the system to use /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/pg_hba.conf as the main configuration file, which it isn't.  I don't know if that is what you are doing or not.  If you want to use a custom pg_hba.conf, the easiest way would be to over-write the default one with your custom one.  You could also create a custom postgresql.conf file which points to your custom pg_hba.conf file (by setting the hba_file parameter in postgresql.conf)

Comment: i concluded on the same answer today before looking at this, just going to overwrite with the default. best.